# Decorating JTextArea

Tags: java, swing, fonts, jtextarea

I'm appending text to a text area using .append method, I've been trying to make the text which gets appended bold and also change colour.

Is this not possible with JTextArea area, I only want one line to be bold and a different colour and the rest the default font.

Do I need to use something other than JTextArea?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

For having different lines/words/characters with different Font or colour setting  you need either JTextPane or JEditorPane, [How to Use Editor Panes and Text Panes](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/editorpane.html).

In JTextArea, the whole document is bound to have one single setting in terms of FONT or COLOUR.

Hope this might help.

Regards

Answer (score 3):

`JTextArea` is for plain text. `JTextPane` can show attributed text.